# Cakephp 1.3 model validation errors

Tags: cakephp-1.3

I'm doing some basic model validation for a user model, but unfortunately, the validation is not working correctly.

These are my errors:

1. If "required" is used, the error message always appears
2. If "required" is not used, no error message even if incorrect variable entered (ie: Typing the letter A for name.
3. Email is validating on "name-gmail.com" which is obviously not an email

HELP! PLEASE!

Here is my validate variable in my model:

```
var $validate = array(
    'name' => array(
        'length' => array(
           'rule' => array('minLength', 2),
           'message'   => 'Please enter your first name (more than 2 chars)',
           'required' => true,
        ),
    ),
    'username' => array(
        'length' => array(
            'rule'      => array('minLength', 5),
            'message'   => 'Must be more than 5 characters',
        ),
        'alphanum' => array(
            'rule'      => 'alphanumeric',
            'message'   => 'May only contain letters and numbers',
        ),
        'unique' => array(
            'rule'      => 'isUnique',
            'message'   => 'Already taken',
            'required' => true,
        ),
    ),
    'email' => array(
        'email' => array(
            'rule'      => 'email',
            'message'   => 'Must be a valid email address',
        ),
        'unique' => array(
            'rule'      => 'isUnique',
            'message'   => 'Already taken',
        ),
    ),
    'password' => array(
        'empty' => array(
            'rule'      => 'notEmpty',
            'message'   => 'Must not be blank',
            'required'  => true,
        ),
    ),
    'password_confirm' => array(
        'compare'    => array(
            'rule'      => array('password_match', 'password', true),
            'message'   => 'The password you entered does not match',
            'required'  => true,
        ),
        'length' => array(
            'rule'      => array('between', 6, 20),
            'message'   => 'Use between 6 and 20 characters',
        ),
        'empty' => array(
            'rule'      => 'notEmpty',
            'message'   => 'Must not be blank',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [the docs](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1145/One-Rule-Per-Field). I'm unsure the email validation fails. If you want 'better' validation try:

```
'email' => array(
    'rule' => array('email', true),
    'message' => 'Must be a valid email address'
)
```